# Adding product into a cart using PHP and jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to add my product into the cart using PHP and jQuery. So, in the product I have `onclick` event as `onClick = cartAction('add','here_id_of_product')`.

And the function as:

```js
function cartAction(action,product_code) {
var queryString = "";
    if(action != "") {
        switch(action) {
            case "add":
                queryString = 'action='+action+'&code='+ product_code+'&quantity=1';
            break;
            case "remove":
                queryString = 'action='+action+'&code='+ product_code;
            break;
            case "empty":
                queryString = 'action='+action;
            break;
        }
    }
    jQuery.ajax({
    url: "models/ajax_action.php",
    data:queryString,
    type: "POST",
    success:function(data){
    alert(data);
        $("#cart-item").html(data);
    },
    error:function (){}
    });
}
```

And my ajax_action.php is

```
<?php
 include 'config.php';

  $id = $_POST["code"];

  if(!empty($_POST["action"])) {
  switch($_POST["action"]) {
    case "add":
    if(!empty($_POST["quantity"])) {
    $productByCode = fetchProductbyIDforCart($id);
        $itemArray = array(fetchProductbyIDforCart($id)=>array('pname'=>$productByCode['pname'],'id'=>$productByCode['id'],'quantity'=>$_POST['quantity'],'price'=>$productByCode['price']));
   if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
            if(in_array($productByCode['id'],$_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
                foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $k => $v) {
                        if($productByCode['id'] == $k)
                            $_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"] = $_POST["quantity"];
                }
            } else {
                $_SESSION["cart_item"] = array_merge($_SESSION["cart_item"],$productByCode);
            }
        } else {
            $_SESSION["cart_item"] = $productByCode;
        }
    }
break;
case "remove":
    if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
        foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $k => $v) {
                if($_POST["code"] == $k)
                    unset($_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]);
                if(empty($_SESSION["cart_item"]))
                    unset($_SESSION["cart_item"]);
        }
    }
break;
case "empty":
    unset($_SESSION["cart_item"]);
break;
 }
 }
    print_r($_SESSION["cart_item"]);
?>
```

And function is

```
function fetchProductbyIDforCart($id){
  global $mysqli;
  $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT
pname,
price,
id,
img1,
discount
FROM product
WHERE id = ?
 ");
 $stmt->bind_param("s",$id);
 $stmt->execute();
 $stmt->bind_result($pname,$price,$id,$img1,$discount);
 while ($stmt->fetch()) {
   $row = array('pname' => $pname ,'price'=>$price,'id'=>$id,'img1'=>$img1,'discount'=>$discount );
  }
 $stmt->close();
 if(!empty($row)){
 return $row;
  } else {
   return "";
  }
 }
```

The problem I am facing in the

> Warning:  Illegal offset type in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/stephane/ecomm/models/ajax_action.php on line 11

which is the declaration of an array $itemArray. Where and I going wrong?

Comment: Just break it into two lines.

Comment: it looks like your `fetchProductbyIDforCart` function is returning an `array`, and you're trying to index based on this value, which is not allowed.

Comment: @QuietOran Then How can i achieve it.

Comment: @Akintunde007 Can you help me writing into Answer

Comment: see my answer below @NikitaAgrawal

Answer (score 0):

Your `fetchProductbyIDforCart` is returning an `array`, which is not allowed as an index type for an array, as stated here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

If you're looking to associate the `id` value with the `fetchProductbyIDforCart`, then I would suggest doing something like this:

```
$itemArray = array($id=>fetchProductbyIDforCart($id));
```

**EDIT**

Looking at your code more, your `$itemArray` isn't even being used, you could just remove it. And your `$_SESSION['cart_item']` should carry persistence.

Comment: But by doing so whenever i am adding items in cart , The previous added cart item is getting removed.

Comment: I edited my answer, from the looks of it though, the itemArray isn't getting used.

Answer (score 0):

How many array did you want to create?
It seems you try to create $itemArray as an array of array.
I can suggest you to review your code.
In the line of the error you wrote:

```
        $itemArray = array(fetchProductbyIDforCart($id)=>array('pname'=>$productByCode['pname'],'id'=>$productByCode['id'],'quantity'=>$_POST['quantity'],'price'=>$productByCode['price']));
```

the function called "fetchProductByIDforCart" already return an array.
Go to see the statement where there is the return and you can see:

```
return $row;
```

the variable $row is already an array.

And at last but not the last I've found that you doesn't get the result of the query to fill the result.

I can't see where you get the result of the query in this code:

```
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
```

$row = array('pname' => $pname ,'price'=>$price,'id'=>$id,'img1'=>$img1,'discount'=>$discount );
  }